# Apache TomCat as web server and container

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, webserver

I have Apache tomcat 7 where I build my web application and I also have Apache Web Server where my web site exist wrote on Css and HTML. I want to inject my web app on web site. *How can I make my Tomcat as web server and container and transfer web site from Apache  WebServer to Tomcat*. ???

I know tomcat also can work on 80 port. Just I use to read documentation how to integrate Apache WebServer with Tomcat using mod_jk ajp connectors and etc to do, seems like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Tomcat as your web server (to serve your .html and .css files and probably images), then you can just get rid of the Apache Web Server; you no longer need it, according to your question.  Then, after putting all your html/css/etc. under `webapps/[app-root]/`, make sure that all references to port 8080 in Tomcat's `conf/server.xml` are changed to port 80, reboot Tomcat, and you'll be good to go.