# Why won't AJAX change text on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to get to grips with AJAX and JQuery quickly and following the tutorial on W3Schools website.  At this point in the [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) where the button is suppossed to get AJAX to change text with text from a file it will not work on my PC.  In the same location as the HTML file I have a file named "ajax_info.txt" which contains the following text -

AJAX is not a new programming language.

AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.

Here is my code, why won't it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use jquery AJAX instead?

Comment: Have you checked that the request returns with state `4` and status `200`?

Comment: When you run this locally, are you using an actual web server or just opening the HTML file directly?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja because it's not always worth the 80k overhead to do 1 simple ajax request...

Comment: @rorypicko I think they were asking because the question is tagged [jquery].

Comment: When I try it, I get the error message "Access denied". The browser doesn't allow you to request the file from the file system. When you run this in a web server that is not a problem.

Comment: @timus2001 - I am not getting any error when I press the button nothing happens at all

Comment: @NikhilTalreja - I am new to web development and assumed I had to get to grips with Javascript, then AJAX and then JQuery.  I am on AJAX now.

Comment: @David - I am running this simply by opening the HTML file.  I am new to web debvelopment and have never set things up to run with a local server.  Still to learn that too!!

Comment: @user2696089: You need a web server of some kind then.  AJAX operates on HTTP requests, not by accessing the file system.  So the originating page needs to be served by HTTP in order for any of it to work.  There are many free web servers available, your computer may even come with one already.  (IIS for Windows, Apache for Linux, etc.)

Comment: @David -  Okay. It is to build a front end on a Java servlet that was originally created by a contrator.  As I say I am very inexperienced in web in general.  The servlet runs on Tomcat and I found the following link on stack overflow which guided me to have the html and txt file placed in a folder within Tomcats Webapps directory and use Tomcat as the web server and it now appears to work.  Thanks to you and others for guidance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440228/apache-tomcat-as-web-server-and-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are facing is the error (if u check the browser console)

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP
```

And its because you are not using a local server. Try running this using Visual Studio or any similar local server

Comment: Okay. It is to build a front end on a Java servlet that was originally created by a contrator.  As I say I am very inexperienced in web in general.  The servlet runs on Tomcat and I found the following link on stack overflow which guided me to have the html and txt file placed in a folder within Tomcats Webapps directory and use Tomcat as the web server and it now appears to work.  Thanks for guidance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440228/apache-tomcat-as-web-server-and-container